# Switch Statement To Dynamic for filling in parameters

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a more dynamic approach to pulling data for a view than a switch statement. Right now I have several different options and more could be added anytime. The tables that will be pulled from are all the same in format except for the name of the table and the name of their ID field.

```
     public List<listoftables> BuildListOfTables(string router)
    {

        var listOfViewModels = new List<FormatOfTables>();
        using var context = new TableContext();
        switch (router)
        {
            case "firstTable":
                listOfViewModels = context.Set<firstTable>().Select(x => new FormatOfTables
                {
                    UniqueID = x.FirstTableID,
                    Value = x.Value,
                }).ToList();
                break;
            case "secondTable":
                listOfViewModels = context.Set<secondTable>().Select(x => new FormatOfTables
                {
                    UniqueID = x.SecondTableID,
                    Value = x.Value,
                }).ToList();
                break;
            case "thirdTable":
                listOfViewModels = context.Set<ThirdTable>().Select(x => new FormatOfTables
                {
                    UniqueID = x.ThirdTableID,
                    Value = x.Value,
                }).ToList();
                break;
        return listOfViewModels;
        }
```

I'm trying to find a way to do this more dynamically. So as long as the option in router matches a table name, each table that gets put into the model just fills the UniqueID and Value to be whatever their ID and value happens to be rather than having to match the column names. So if a fourth table came in I would only have to worry about if router matched the table name rather than having to add an entirely new switch per entry.

Comment: one way is a `dictionary<string, Action>`

Comment: There's no world where a method declared to return a `List<listofTables>` can actually return a `List<FormatOfTables>`

Comment: @pm100 I don't know that a `Dictionary<string, Action>` actually helps much, since it's mostly the same action every time. If anything I might do a `Dictionary<string, Func<DBSet>>`. But a `Dictionary<string, Type>` that somehow makes it possible to call the `Set<T>()` method could work... but I'm not sure exactly how that would fit together, since the `T` for the `Set()` method has to resolve at compile time.

Comment: You could do an SQL query to get the list of tables from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The tables that will be pulled from are all the same in format except for the name of the table and the name of their ID field.

The problem here is passing the typename to the `Set<T>()` function. But we'll get to that. First, let's make some of this easier by adding an interface:

```
public interface IMyTable
{
   string TableName {get;}
   int UniqueID {get;}
}
```

Then each of your `firstTable`, `secondTable`, `ThirdTable` types must implement this interface:

```
public class firstTable : IMyTable
{
    // existing class stuff here

    public int UniqueID { get { return FirstTableId;} }
    public string TableName { get { return "FirstTable"; } }
}
```

And now the method can look like this:

```
public IEnumerable<listoftables> BuildListOfTables(string router)
{
    using var context = new TableContext();
    DBSet tableSet = null; //I'm making an assumption about the Set() function here. You may need to change the type.
    switch (router)
    {
        case "firstTable":
            tableSet = context.Set<firstTable>();
            break;
        case "secondTable":
            tableSet = context.Set<secondTable>();
            break;
        case "thirdTable":
            tableSet = context.Set<ThirdTable>();
            break;
    }

    if (tableSet != null) 
    {
       return tableSet.Select(x => new FormatOfTables
           {
              UniqueID = x.UniqueID,
              Value = x.Value
           });
    }
    return null;
}
```

This reduces the repeated boilerplate down to just as much as is necessary to call the generic `Set<>()` function.

From here we can further reduce the code by changing how the function is designed, including how you expect to call it:

```
public IEnumerable<listoftables> BuildListOfTables<T>() where T : IMyTable
{
    using var context = new TableContext();
    return context.Set<T>()
           .Select(x => new FormatOfTables
           {
              UniqueID = x.UniqueID,
              Value = x.Value
           });
}
```

But all this really does is push where you have to put the `switch()` statement up to the call site. However, that *might* be worth it if the call site happens to have the type information already available.

Note for ALL of these examples I converted the method to return IEnumerable instead of a List. Calling `.ToList()` can be notoriously bad for performance. If you *really* need a list (hint: you usually don't) you can still put the `?.ToList()` **after** the function call. You might be able to improve things even further in this case by returning `IQueryable`, which could let later code continue the expression tree before executing anything on the server.